# About the violation of the assumption of indentical distributed responses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions

Consider a univariate testing problem. Many statistical tests (such as the t-test) require identical distributed responses, that is subjects homogeneous with respect to all unobserved covariates. I was wondering what happens when this assumption is violated.

As far as I know, if the data are paired and if we use as statistical test the mean of differences (before and after treatment), there's no need for the responses to be identical distributed, in fact differences become covariate-free. Here is the proof.
Be $Y_{1i}$ the response for the ith unit on occasion 1 (before the treatment), and $Y_{2i}$ the response for the same unit on occasion 2 (after the treatment). We can assume this model for the responses:
$Y_{1i}=\mu+\eta_{i}+\epsilon_{1i}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;i=1,...,n$
$Y_{2i}=\mu+\eta_{i}-\delta+\epsilon_{2i}\;\;\;i=1,...,n$
where $\mu$ is a population constant, $\delta$ is the constant additive treatment effect, $\eta_{i}$ are the unobserved covariates for the ith unit, $\epsilon_{1i}$ and $\epsilon_{1i}$ are identically distributed centred random deviates. The differences are covariate-free:
$X_{i} = Y_{1i} − Y_{2i} = \delta + \epsilon_{1i} − \epsilon_{2i}, i = 1,..., n$

Now, let's consider a two sample design. What happens if subjects are not homogeneous? Can we still use the test? Are the results misleading?
For instance, suppose that we have two groups of individuals. Group A receives the treatment while group B receives a placebo. Suppose that in each sample some are males while the remaining are females. Suppose that we don't know the sex of each unit and that we only know the value of the univariate response.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking, because you posit sharply contradictory situations.  By definition, in a "univariate testing problem" *there are no covariates.*  Moreover, when data are paired you typically are testing their differences and indeed you need special procedures if those differences are not identically distributed and independent; the meaning of "covariate-free" is really obscure here.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, John.  Could you please explain what you mean by a subject to be "homogeneous with respect to all unobserved covariates"?  Is this intended to mean that the distributions of $\epsilon_{1i}-\epsilon_{2i}$ may vary over $i$? Also, why are you subscripting $n_1$ and $n_2$? Your definition of $X_i$ makes sense only when $n=n_1=n_2$.

Comment: I added more information and corrected some mistakes.

Comment: I still have some trouble following this question. I think there are some confusions behind this (although that may be reason enough to re-open & have someone clear this up). I suspect you are thinking about what econometricians call *fixed effects regression*. That is, you can validly draw causal inferences from a before & after study if all of the variables that could confound the effect are constant for the units. That doesn't really apply to 2 independent groups studies.